# Foreach loop on dynamic number of checkboxes, get name

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

So I have this concept (which I'm open to the possibility of it being a bad concept) to loop through a dynamic number of `checkboxes` and take the name of each `checkbox` that has been selected and push it to a hidden text field on my form so that the values of the names of those `checkboxes` that have been selected can be used elsewhere in my application.  However, being somewhat new to JQuery I'm not sure if this can be done or how it can be done.  This is what I've got so far with my research:

Relevant JQuery:

```
    $('#saveButton').click(function () {

      $('checkbox').each(function () {
          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              $('#hiddenDate').append($(this).text());
          }
      });
   });
```

Relevant View code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<% using (Html.BeginForm("SaveExit", "User", new { }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "selectExitPoints" }))    { %>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="title center xl">Event&nbsp;Exit&nbsp;Selection&nbsp;</div>
        <table class="data-table">
        <%var odd = true; %>
        <%foreach (var log in Model.Log.OrderBy(s => s.DateEntered))
        { %>
            <tr class="row_<%=(odd ? "odd" : "even")%>">
                <td><input class="skill-checkbox" name="<%=log.DateEntered%>" type="checkbox" /></td>
                <td><span class="skill-text"><%= log.DateEntered%></span></td>
                <td><span class="skill-text"><%= log.EntryAccessPoint %></span></td>
            </tr>
            <%odd = !odd;%>
        <% } %>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" id="hiddenDate" />
    </fieldset>
<% } %>
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: If a user clicks a checkbox on and off repeatedly, that `hiddenDate` is going to get really long.

Comment: `$('checkbox')` should be `$(':checkbox')` or, better yet, `$('[type=checkbox]')`

Comment: That's why I put that particular function within the save function -- so that hiddenDate only gets filled once when the user gets directed away from the page as the save function will also perform a redirect

Comment: @Blazemonger that produces the following error: 'TypeError: Object [type=checkbox] has no method 'each''

Comment: Then you didn't type it correctly.

Comment: You are correct.  It runs fine, however it does not populate the hidden textfield with anything as it is so I have accepted another answer down below.  Thank you very much anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [jQuery .map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/). Just like that :

```
var values = $.map($(':checkbox:checked'), function(el){
    return $(el).prop('name');
})
$('input').val(values.join(','));
```

Comment: with my version of JQuery which I can't recall right now this worked by changing .prop to .attr so thank you!

Comment: Yeah prop is for jquery >1.6, atleast you figured the problem!